# __some_wrapper__ syntax (when to use and not use)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have seen this syntax in ruby for a number of items and I wanted to learn more about when it's used.

```
def  __some_wrapper__
  @__some_wrapper__ ||= SomeClass.new(self)
end
```

When and where are two lower dashes `__` before and after a name used? What's the rule for it? I have seen it used for method names, and such.

Comment: If only there were some way to mark Ruby methods as `private` so developers knew they should stay away from them! If only.

Comment: @anothermh: Unfortunately, good names are finite resources. For example, `send` is a good name for a method that sends a message to an object, it is also a good name for a method that sends an email. Now, if you write an `Email` class that has a `send` method, you have just broken reflection. That's why Ruby calls the method `__send__` (and provides `send` only as an optional alias).

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen this syntax in ruby for a number of items and I wanted to learn more about when it's used.

This is just a method definition like any other method definition. An underscore is a legal part of an identifier. It doesn't have any special meaning whatsoever.

> When and where are two lower dashes `__` before and after a name used? What's the rule for it? I have seen it used for method names, and such.

As with any other name, a developer uses such a name when she thinks that it is the right name to use for this thing. There is absolutely no difference whatsoever between the names `✅` or `foo` or `add` or `__some_wrapper__`. You choose the name which best conveys the intent of the method.